# Why Struts 2 annotations don't have LongRangeFieldValidator

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, struts-validation, xwork

I was working on validation using annotation in Struts2 and i was quite surprised to see that the annotations does not have a `LongRangeFieldValidator` where as the validations done using xml does have a [`LongRangeFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/LongRangeFieldValidator.html)

I tried different ways to get the `LongRangeFieldValidor` using annotations.

1. [`LongRangeFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/LongRangeFieldValidator.html). It showed an error because it doesn't actually exists and `com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.validators.LongRangeFieldValidator` cannot be converted to an `Annotation` type. This was quite obvious so i switched to next.
2. I used [`IntRangeFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/IntRangeFieldValidator.html). I could quite use it because it was unable to do a typecasting. I thought this should have worked because docs says it is for numeric types.
3. [`DoubleRangeFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/DoubleRangeFieldValidator.html) This one also validates (and it should) non-integer values so i had to drop this.
4. Finally I had to convert my `long` field to a `String` and had to use [`RegexFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/RegexFieldValidator.html).

My question is why there isn't a `LongRangeFieldValidator` in the package [`com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/package-summary.html) and what are the best practices to obtain it?

Comment: The short answer to "why" is "just because", likely an oversight. It's probably worth filing a JIRA ticket, though, since there should be one-to-one mappings between the XML and annotations, and we'll add it.

Comment: As Dave said, feel free to register JIRA issue for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they forgot to add this annotation to the core package. Just a mistake may be or so, but there is the workaround. Use a [custom validator](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/CustomValidator.html) annotation

```
@CustomValidator(type ="long", fieldName = "myField")
```

under [registered validators](http://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html#Validation-RegisteringValidators) you can find the name of the validator `long`.